# Replace searched text with additional text to it in netbeans

Tags: php, html, regex, netbeans, replace

I'm using NetBeans, and in my project im having many plain text strings (string1, string2, string3...) like below.

```
<div class="xyz" id="abc"><strong>string1</strong></div>
<p>string2</p>
<h1>string3</h1>
```

I need to replace those string like below.

```
<div class="xyz" id="abc"><strong><?php echo __('string1'); ?></strong></div>
<p><?php echo __('string2'); ?></p>
<h1><?php echo __('string3'); ?></h1>
```

I'm searching the string manually, because it contains different HTML tags and different string values.

How can i replace that searched particular string with the code wrapped around it in NetBeans ?

Comment: [`(?s)<(\w+)>([^<>]+)</\1>` => `<$1><?php echo __('$2'); ?></$1>`](https://regex101.com/r/tauS4K/1)? If you need to only match tags that have alphanumeric/`_` chars in their node values, you may replace `[^<>]+` with `\w+`. If the tags may have attributes, use `<(\w+)[^>]*>` instead of `<(\w+)>`. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/tauS4K/2).